# iOS10 Facebook login pops to root view controller

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, facebook-login, ios10

The problem: 
When the facebook app is not installed on the device, a web view is opened in my app where the user can grant permissions to my app. When this is completed, the webview closes and **the root view controller of the parent UINavigationController (2. in hirarchy) is shown.**

I'm using FBSDK 4.17 on iOS10.

First facebook login is being called like so:

```
loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
    self.loginCompleted(result: result, error: error)
}
```

from a UIViewController in the following hierarchy:

1. UIViewController (where the login is triggered from)
2. UINavigationController
3. UITabBarController

However, I want to simply return to the same view controller which the facebook login was initiated from and not it's UINavigationController's rootViewController.

*I am not experiencing the issue where the web view doesn't close. I did implement `application:openUrl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked around this issue by embedding the UIViewController which triggers Facebook login in it's own UINavigationController where I made it the rootViewController.

While this works, the behaviour from the Facebook SDK seems odd and isn't documented anywhere.